# How to perform Instance Segmentation using Tensorflow?

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, object-detection, faster-rcnn

I used Tensorflow Object Detection API for a custom dataset based on the instructions at this [help](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/research/object_detection/g3doc/using_your_own_dataset.md) document.As required , collected the dataset,annotated it in PASCAL VOC XML format,split into training and test sets,generated tfrecords. Pets configuration for custom object detection and localization is used.

I just want to proceed further and get segmentation boundary rather than bounding box. The [link](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/research/object_detection/g3doc/running_locally.md) is clear till this point on directory structure and mechanism to prepare input data.

Instance Segmentation [help](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/research/object_detection/g3doc/instance_segmentation.md) is unclear to me on two aspects: 
  -Directory structure
  -Is it required to supply segment boundaries equal in number to that of images in training and test sets ?

Notice that tfrecords are created using [this](https://gist.github.com/saghiralfasly/ee642af0616461145a9a82d7317fb1d6) script. Can this be reused to include segmentation data.

Comment: Matterport Mask RCNN Keras/Tensorflow library https://github.com/matterport/Mask_RCNN is a good starting point for instance segmentation. There are some good example notebooks and some datasets so maybe it might help.